# Xamarin forms listview context action doesn't work with details

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I use XF listview with menu context action and viewcell selected by tap.
The context actions don't work when I implemented TapGestureReconizer.

My code is here:

```
    <ListView x:Name="PaymentCardsListView"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PaymentCardsList}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPaymentCard, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditCommand, Source={x:Reference PaymentCardsListView}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            Text="Edit"/>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference PaymentCardsListView}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            IsDestructive="true"
                            Text="Delete"/>
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DetailCommand, Source={x:Reference PaymentCardsListView}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Expiry Date: "/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ExpMonth}"/>
                                <Label Text="/"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ExpYear}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I need to work with context menu and stacklayout tap. 
How should I implement this?

It works on iOS.
The issue is only on Android.

Answer (score 1):

I found confirmed bug on bugzilla.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46363

I'm thinking about walkthrough.
One of them it create custom renderer for view cell for android and override LongPress for display custom menu.

Comment: If you found your solution, you could accept your own answer.